# Show a specific part of an Item when selected in a ComboBox

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I have a ComboBox that shows the name of every country and its mobile code.
I want the ComboBox to show only the Country Code when I select the item and not its name.
For example, I have `Albania +355`; I want to see only the Code (`+355`) when I select it.
The items are written in the `Items` collection property.
Is there any code that can do that?

I haven't tried much since I have no idea how that can be done, the only thing I have tried is `comboBox6.Text = "";` but that deletes the whole text.

Comment: Hi Simon, welcome to Stackoverflow, can you provide code which sets value to `comboBox6 `

Comment: @PrasadTelkikar but i have written all the items in the (items) Property.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion si to build a class that holds all the values you need, then use a `List<class>` to set the [ComboBox.DataSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.combobox.datasource) property.

Set the **`DisplayMember`** to the name of the property to use as the List visible string and the **`ValueMember`** to the Property name you want to use as the `ComboBox.Text`.

Then you can just set the `ComboBox.Text` to **`ComboBox.SelectedValue.ToString()`** (`SelectedValue`, as `SelectedItem`, is an `object`, you need to cast it. You know it's a string, so just *convert* it).
The `ComboBox.Text` must be set after a small delay (after the control has already changed the Text on its own). This can be done calling [Control.BeginInvoke()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.begininvoke) with an Action that changes the Text to what we need.

Using a simple class object to store the values:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    comboBox1.DisplayMember = "CountryAndCode";
    comboBox1.ValueMember = "Code";
    comboBox1.DataSource = countryCodes;
    comboBox1.SelectedIndex = -1;

    comboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged += (o, ev) => {
        if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex < 0) return;
        comboBox1.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => {
            comboBox1.Text = comboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString();
        }));
    };
}

public List<CountryCode> countryCodes = new List<CountryCode>() {
    new CountryCode() { Country = "USA", Code = "+1" },
    new CountryCode() { Country = "Canada", Code = "+1" },
    new CountryCode() { Country = "Argentina", Code = "+54"},
    new CountryCode() { Country = "Brasil", Code = "+55"}
};
```

The class definition:

```
public class CountryCode
{
    public CountryCode() { }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string CountryAndCode => this.ToString();

    public override string ToString() => this.Country + (char)32 + this.Code;
}
```

**Note**: **`comboBox1.SelectedItem`** is a **`CountryCode`** class object. You just need to cast it to `CountryCode` to read all the properties from this Item.

```
var item = comboBox1.SelectedItem as CountryCode;
string selectedName = item.Country;
string selectedCode = item.Code; // etc.
```

If you instead want to keep the simple string format, you can use a `List<string>`.
It's more or less the same thing (except a loss in flexibility). You can extract the Country Code from the **`ComboBox.SelectedItem`**, using [string.LastIndexOf()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.lastindexof) to determine the position of the **`+`** char in the string:

```
private List<string> simpleCountryCodes = new List<string>() {
    "USA +1", "Canada +1", "Argentina +54", "Brasil +55"
};

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    comboBox1.DataSource = simpleCountryCodes;
    comboBox1.SelectedIndex = -1;

    comboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged += (o, ev) => {
        if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex < 0) return;
        string item = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
        string code = item.Substring(item.LastIndexOf("+"));
        comboBox1.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => { comboBox1.Text = code; }));
    };
 }
```

Should you decide to convert the **`List<string>`** to a **`List<CountryCode>`**, you can use LINQ to generate **`CountryCode`** objects from the strings like this:

```
var countryCodes = new List<CountryCode>();
countryCodes.AddRange(simpleCountryCodes.Select(c => new CountryCode() {
    Code = c.Substring(c.LastIndexOf("+")),
    Country = c.Substring(0, c.IndexOf("+") - 1)
}).ToArray());
```

This is how it works in both cases:

[image: ComboBox Text Custom Action]

Answer (score 0):

Put a TextBox and a ComboBox on your Form and then do like this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private Dictionary<string, string> countryCodes = new Dictionary<string, string>()
    {
        { "Albania", "Albania +355" },
        { "USA", "USA +1" },
        { "Iran", "Iran +98" },
    };

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        comboBox1.Items.AddRange(countryCodes.Values.ToArray());
    }

    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = countryCodes.Where(x => x.Value == comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()).First().Key;
    }
}
```

[image]

After selecting an item:

[image]

**Edit:**
If you want to see the code in your textbox you can change countryInfo to:

```
private Dictionary<string, string> coubtryCodes = new Dictionary<string, 
string>()
{
     { "+355", "Albania +355" },
     { "+1", "USA +1" },
     { "+98", "Iran +98" },
};
```